# Output format for a still image from avconv

Tags: image, format, output, avconv

I'd like to generate a still image from my video in mpeg to pipe, something like

```
avconv -ss 0:01 -i my.mpg -frames:v 1 -f jpeg -
```

However, avconv (ffmpeg) does not have jpeg among allowed output formats. There is no problem to specify format by output extension:

```
avconv -ss 0:01 -i my.mpg -frames:v 1 my.jpg; cat my.jpg
```

but I don't want to create redundant files. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://libav.org/avconv.html#pipe), you can pipe to stdout by setting the output filename as the pipe protocol, i.e. `pipe:1`. And though it's not stated explicitly, you can set the output format as a file extension, the same way you would for a normal filename:

```
avconv -ss 0:01 -i my.mpg -frames:v 1 pipe:1.jpg
```

Sidenote:

> Note that some formats (typically MOV), require the output protocol to be seekable, so they will fail with the pipe output protocol